# How to attach a drawing surface to QMainWindow?

Tags: qt

The top-level view in the application I am working on is not Qt-based. This view has its own APIs to draw lines, pixels, etc. I would like to take a rectangular portion of this view and attach it to QMainWindow instance. I guess there must be some mechanism within Qt that attaches a screen (Windows, x-windows, etc.) to QMainWindow. Can you please direct me to the abstract class that Qt uses for drawing to the actual surface? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt4 there's `QX11EmbedWidget`, which doesn't actually seem to exist in Qt5 and I can't find a good replacement. In terms of surface rendering everything is done as a `QPaintDevice` if it's subclassed from `QWidget` (which as far as I know every GUI element is).

Answer (score 0):

The default raster backend draws on a `QImage`, so what you paint on with a `QPainter` in any widget is a `QImage`.

The backing store `QImage` shares the image bits with the underlying platform. On Windows, the `QImage` accesses a DIB section's data directly. On X11, the `QImage` accesses a shared memory `XImage`.

In all cases, assuming that your non-Qt code expects a bitmap to paint on, you can pass the data pointer from the `QImage` to the non-Qt code, within the `paint` event:

```
QImage * image = dynamic_cast<QImage*>(backingStore()->paintDevice());
```

The non-Qt code needs to properly interface to a large bitmap: it needs to accept a starting scan line to draw on, an X offset, and scanline length.